# PHP start task for certain time

Tags: php, tabs, task, cron

Im having a small problem i searched a while about it but didnt found any good aswer for my problem , so here it is:

I have a PHP script with user database and i want users to have a small button that will make a certain task execute for a certain time ( imagine 2 hours ) , and this task will keep running till the job is done. The user can stop the task and hit continue , and the task will stop executing after 2 hours!

Any ideia how i can do it?

My actual hosting have crontab.

Comment: Must it be 2hrs ??? What about batch Processing ? What kind of process is this ... more information needed

Comment: which part do you need help with? Initiating the task, or making it stop after 2 hours?

Comment: I need the script to start running ( even if the user close the browser after hit start ) and the script should stop after 2 hour of execution or after some limit verified!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you haven't explained your problem in enough details , but you should this generally :

when users post tasks , write these tasks in a database table, with other information such as start time and end time (and you can update these due to user new input), then write a script which reads these tasks from database and compares current time to start time and if it is time to run, runs the task.
now put this single script in a cron job

This is actually a better idea than creating a cron job for each user defined task

Comment: Thanks for you reply , actually i can describe better my problem , when the user hits button like "START PROCESS" a background process should start till the job is done or after a period of time ! Using crons is not an option because i dont need the script to be executed in a certain hour , i just need task done fast as i can. Also how can i make the script stop if the user want change a variable that influence the job? 
EDIT : dont forget , process must continue after user hits "start"

Comment: But this will make all the processes run at the same time , wich will cause a server overload. isnt iT?

Comment: No. this script should be run for example every 5 minutes. in each execution, it reads tasks from database and checks if it is time to start any of the tasks. So it depends on the number of tasks and the the time are specified to run. So only tasks which have similar start time will be processed at the same time

Comment: @Pedro Martins : you can increase frequency of execution of this script , if it is important to run the tasks with lower delay.